# Linq to SQL and ADO.net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have databae and tables now in viual studio first i try to work with LINQ to SQL so when i select add new item then LINQ to SQL then DataClasses1.dbml file is created so with the refrence of this i create select function like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string select()
{
    DataClasses1DataContext d = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var q = from a in d.GetTable<test>()
            select a;
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return json.Serialize(q);
}
```

and second method i use with the refrence of dataclasses1.dbml like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string select_data()
{
    List<selectdataResult> dq = d.selectdata().ToList();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    //dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Maths", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Eng", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Science", typeof(int));

    foreach (var c in dq)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(c.name, c.Eng, c.Maths, c.Science);

    }


    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return json.Serialize(dq);
}
```

**ADO.NET(ENTITY FRAMEWORK)**

second method I use entity framework I select ado.net and extract all tables and sp so I create function like `select_data`

so my question what is the difference .. in linq to sql we able to do through calling sp and also writing whole linq query in ado.net we also use write linq query and calling sp

so what is difference?

and what is gettable in this line `var q = from a in d.GetTable<test>()`
if we select data from multiple tables then what we do in this line

Comment: As an side, LinqToSql has been obsolete since the 4.0 release of Entity Framework (when EF gained all of the features of LinqToSql). Is there a reason you're using LinqToSql instead of Entity Framework?

Comment: no.. i heard linq is very powerful and less lines of code and easy to use so thats why i use LINQ.. now you told that EF gained all feature of LINQtoSQL.. so why still there is option of LINQtoSQL @Dai

Comment: Entity Framework is the successor to LinqToSql and it does use Linq (search for "Linq-to-Entities"). LinqToSql is retained in the .NET Framework for backwards-compatibility for projects that already use it, but for new projects you should use EF. I appreciate that the Visual Studio "Add New Item" dialog does not make this clear and I wish the Visual Studio team would annotate the Item Template to make this obvious.

Comment: so mean instead of LINQtoSQL option we select ado.net entity data model?? and the features i wrote is right/?

Comment: Yes. Entity Framework's Item Template is called "ADO.NET Entity Data Model".

Comment: ok thanku..........